# Cannot install project's dependencies (errors logged by the cdm)

Tags: node.js, shell, terminal

I was trying to install the sqlite3 package needed for a project, and when trying to do so on my command prompt i get a bunch of errors.
I do not know whether it is me that tries to install packages in the wrong directory or if it is my windows PC.

Errors shown when trying to install project's dependencies (npm i sqlite3):

```
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\Downloads\example_backend\example_backend\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\Downloads\example_backend\example_backend\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\Downloads\example_backend\example_backend\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.17.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\Downloads\example_backend\example_backend\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.1.1/node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.1.1/node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.1.1/node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.1.1 and node@16.17.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.1.1/node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.5 found at "C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:364:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:385:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:408:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Simone Ghilotti\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\Simone Ghilotti\\Downloads\\example_backend\\example_backend\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v93-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Simone Ghilotti\\Downloads\\example_backend\\example_backend\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v93-win32-x64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\Downloads\example_backend\example_backend\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\Downloads\example_backend\example_backend\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\Downloads\example_backend\example_backend\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\Downloads\example_backend\example_backend\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Simone Ghilotti\\Downloads\\example_backend\\example_backend\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\Downloads\example_backend\example_backend\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Simone Ghilotti\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-20T08_49_15_500Z-debug-0.log
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you all in advance !

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs for `node-gyp` that are referenced in the error message?

Comment: I tried to install the newest version of VS (with the desktop tools with C++) as stated in the errors but it still prints out the same error

Answer (score 1):

remove package-lock.json, and run npm install